# Client Cancelled Exception when running Apache FlinkRunner via HuggingFace Datasets

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-beam, dill, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to download wikipedia corpora through HuggingFace's Datasets library. Most of the languages I've needed have downloaded successfully, but I cannot seem to get Cebuano, Spanish, or Russian to finish downloading. Here is an example of how I'm trying to do this (Colab Notebook):

```py
!pip install datasets
!pip install apache_beam
!pip install mwparserfromhell

import os
from datasets import load_dataset
import apache_beam as beam
import mwparserfromhell
from google.colab import drive

drive_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'drive')
drive.mount(drive_dir)

lang = 'ru' # or 'ceb' or 'es'

lang_dir = os.path.join(drive_dir, 'path/to/training/dir', lang)
if not os.path.exists(lang_dir):
  x = load_dataset('wikipedia', '20220301.' + lang, beam_runner='Flink',
                   split='train')
  x.save_to_disk(lang_dir)
```

I have also tried playing with the versions of `dill`, `requests`, and `protobuf` because the `pip install` commands will often produce warnings about compatibility issues. However, the main problem I am encountering is that the above code will run with only a few warnings produced (these warnings were produced for other languages which downloaded successfully) for several hours before suddenly producing the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
[/tmp/ipykernel_219/3869142325.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>
     18   x = None
     19   x = load_dataset('wikipedia', '20220301.' + lang, beam_runner='Flink',
---> 20                    split='train')
     21   x.save_to_disk(lang_dir)

3 frames
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in wait_until_finish(self, duration)
    604 
    605     if self._runtime_exception:
--> 606       raise self._runtime_exception
    607 
    608     return self._state

RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-root-0618220708-b3b59a0e_d8efcf67-9119-4f76-b013-70de7b29b54d failed in state FAILED: org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p43p2.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client cancelled
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I thought about submitting a ticket to Apache Beam on GitHub, but they are overrun with open issues and will likely never touch my ticket in time (I'm using these datasets for an internship project).

The documentation for Datasets is somewhat above my pay grade as I'm new to machine learning as well as the tools Datasets relies on. I have tried to find a way to specify more specific pipeline options, but I can't seem to figure out what to do beyond choosing a runner and letting Datasets decide the rest. I want to be clear that the actual operation of the pipeline is totally abstracted from me as far as I can tell, and I'm not sure if I have control over that here.

Any help is appreciated, and I would even be grateful if someone could direct me to a repo where these datasets have already been downloaded/cleaned via the Datasets library. Thank you!

Comment: Turns out that this is a memory leak of some kind. I don't know all the details, but in case anyone else ever finds this useful, I have solved my own problem. You can download and clean a Wikipedia yourself using the WikiExtractor tool and a bit of your own code:

https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor

Here is some code I wrote to concatenate the files produced together and strip the <doc> tags:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10sQPgfRc3vVhTyoku3kiKgsJKcNEQHuD?usp=sharing